# Find records where length of array equal to - Rails 4

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my `Room` model, I have an attribute named `available_days`, which is being stored as an array.

For example:

```
Room.first.available_days
=> ["wed", "thurs", "fri"]
```

What is the best way to find all Rooms where the size of the array is equal to 3?

I've tried something like

```
Room.where('LENGTH(available_days) = ?', 3)
```

with no success.

**Update:** the data type for `available_days` is a string, but in order to store an array, I am serializing the attribute from my model:

app/models/room.rb

```
serialize  :available_days
```

Comment: Can you change the schema? Using `serialize` is almost always a horrible mistake, starts out quick and easy and then blows up in your face.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using postgres you can parse the serialized string to an array type, then query on the length of the array. I expect other databases may have similar approaches. How to do this depends on how the text is being serialized, but by default for Rails 4 should be YAML, so I expect you data is encoded like this:

```
---
- first
- second
```

The following SQL will remove the leading `---\n-`  as well as the final newline, then split the remaining string on `-`  into an array. It's not strictly necessary to cleanup the extra characters to find the length, but if you want to do other operations you may find it useful to have a cleaned up array (no leading characters or trailing newline). This will only work for simple YAML arrays and simple strings.

```
Room.where("ARRAY_LENGTH(STRING_TO_ARRAY(RTRIM(REPLACE(available_days,'---\n- ',''),'\n'), '\n- '), 1) = ?", 3)
```

As you can see, this approach is rather complex. If possible you may want to add a new structured column (array or jsonb) and migrate the serialized string into the a typed column to make this easier and more performant. Rails supports [jsonb serialization for postgres](https://dev.to/kputra/rails-postgresql-jsonb-part-1-4ibg).